Upgrade to 24.04 while on KDE Plasma crashed my system
I switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu about a year ago. I run KDE Plasma 6.2 on a Dell 3700 with a Core i7 processor. It's a small desktop, with a 500GB SSD internal drive, and a 100GB external SSD, and I have 3G2GB RAM. It shows up in the BIOS as an Inspiron.
Last week I received a prompt to upgrade my operating system to Ubuntu 24.04, and when I selected it, it completely crashed my system. I just managed to finally get Plasma 6.2 installed, and after all the system security updates I still get a prompt to upgrade my operating system from Ubuntu.
When I accepted the prompt to upgrade, it completely crashed my system. In fact it was so bad that the tech couldn't even figure it out, and I was forced to buy a new computer.
Now after installing KDE Plasma and upgrading to 6.2 I receive the same notification to upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04. I just can't decide whether or not to go ahead and click to accept the upgrade after I've done all this work (transferred 2,700 photos, my manuscript, etc.). Should I upgrade it?

@karel No.....it's actually a small desktop, with a 500gb SSD internal drive, and a 100gb external SSD, and I have 32gb RAM.  It shows up in the BIOS as an Inspiron. This is the new one i purchased from a reseller. I just managed to FINALLY get Plasma 6.2 installed, and I still after all the system security updates, get the message from Ubuntu. I just can't decide whether or not to go ahead and click to accept the upgrade after I've done all this work (transferred 2,700 photos, my manuscript, etc...). At least I'm operating.  Ya' know? Sorry I said laptop--I was confused and TIRED.

If your computer completely crashes because of a failed upgrade attempt that indicates that it's skipping the boot menu and trying to boot to Ubuntu directly, but it can't boot so it crashes. The key is whether or not you can still access your computer's UEFI setup utility. If so, assuming that you can access the UEFI setup utility and change the boot sequence, it should be able to bypass the hard drive and boot from any live Linux USB. If that doesn't work just disconnect the cable to the 500GB SSD, change the boot sequence, shut down the computer, reconnect the SSD, insert an Ubuntu installation USB, and reboot. Then you could run an Ubuntu live session to test if your Dell 3700's hardware is working properly.
Upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is the worst LTS to the next LTS upgrade that I've ever been informed about here at Ask Ubuntu, so instead of upgrading I fresh installed Ubuntu 24.04, and that had problems too. Fortunately it was a fresh install, so I could fix whatever didn't work and my Ubuntu 24.04 is working like it's supposed to now. If this had been an upgrade instead of a fresh install I might have gotten stuck.

Thank you!  Appreciate the help!!
